# Prefilling Cognito Forms after initial load

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm working with embedding a Cognito form into a Concrete5 website (v5.6 pending approval on an upgrade)...

I've written a quick block type to embed the form, and that works really well. Prefilling is working perfectly - provided the data is available at page load.

I need want to be able to add some tracking data to an internal field as a prefill.  Unfortunately, this data comes in shortly after page loading completes, whereas the seamless-embed method on Cognito starts the loading process in-line.

I've tried using jQuery's document.ready to delay the Cognito load, but this stalls the loading process and leaves the user staring at an ugly screen.

What I'm *looking* for, is the ability to run something like Cognito.prefill() later on down the track using the *seamless* embed method, where Cognito.prefill() isn't available.  I can do it with the iFrame embed, but I'm trying to stick with the seamless method.

I've gone through the embed.js code and found that prefill() uses postMessage to send a JSON string to the iFrame, but it appears the same handler isn't mapped in the seamless version.  I haven't been able to find where (or if) the prefill data is stored until form submit.

Does anyone know if there's something in the Cognito seamless embed script to work with prefill data?  Or can someone shed light on where the data is stored before submit?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. We would like to review this and take a closer look at what you are looking to set up. Can you submit a Support Request (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/)?